# Moq Interface with Action property

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am currently working with the framework Fleck and I want to mock the interface `IWebSocketConnection`. It has some property of type `Action` and I would like to *raise* theses *events*.

I tried so far without success to raise it as a events like this :

```
fleckInterfaceMock.Raise(mock => mock.OnClose += null);
```

Or even to call it directly like this :

```
fleckInterfaceMock.Object.OnClose();
```

I didn't found anything interesting on the [official documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

The interface :

```
namespace Fleck
{
    public interface IWebSocketConnection
    {
        IWebSocketConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo { get; }
        bool IsAvailable { get; }
        Action<byte[]> OnBinary { get; set; }
        Action OnClose { get; set; }
        Action<Exception> OnError { get; set; }
        Action<string> OnMessage { get; set; }
        Action OnOpen { get; set; }
        Action<byte[]> OnPing { get; set; }
        Action<byte[]> OnPong { get; set; }

        void Close();
        Task Send(byte[] message);
        Task Send(string message);
        Task SendPing(byte[] message);
        Task SendPong(byte[] message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `OnClose` and the other members in the interface are not actually events. They are really `get`-`set` properties whose property types just happen to be delegate types.

For that reason I do not think you can or shall use `Raise` from Moq.

If you want the invocation:

```
// desired use
fleckInterfaceMock.Object.OnClose();
```

to succeed, that requires the `get` accessor to return a non-null `Action`.

You could do it like this:

```
// possible Moq setup
Action a = () => { Console.WriteLine("Testing OnClose."); };
fleckInterfaceMock.Setup(x => x.OnClose).Returns(a);
```

If you want delegate combination (this is not true event subscription; we have no event) of the type:

```
// desired use
fleckInterfaceMock.Object.OnClose += someAction;
```

to succeed, the mock must first tolerate a `get` of the property, like before, and secondly it must tolerate that you `set` the property (it will be `set` to the "sum" of (1) what was returned by the `get`, and (2) `someAction`.

There are many ways you could achieve that. One way is simply:

```
// possible Moq setup
fleckInterfaceMock.SetupProperty(x => x.OnClose);
```

That will simply turn `OnClose` into a property which allows both `get` and `set`, and which remembers what it is `set` to and gives that value back when `get` is called.